# Eclipse pkg-config plugin not working with MSYS2 Mingw on Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, mingw, pkg-config, msys2

I am trying to use gtkmm3 in eclipse on windows with Mingw-w64. I have installed MSYS2 and development tools including pkg-config under Mingw-w64. I have added the mingw and msys2 bin directories to my windows PATH. The commands can be run from a normal windows console.

I installed eclipse (with CDT plugins) and installed the pkg-config plugin for eclipse. When I go to Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Pkg-config there is a list of packages. When I select gtkmm-3.0 the checkbox (and the checkbox for it's dependencies) stays checked, but the include directories are not altered. I still cannot build with the managed build system nor does syntax checking work (I am new to gtk development and would like to be able to have eclipse check syntax). I can build the project using my custom makefile so I know that the libraries are installed and setup correctly.

When I use the same setup in my Ubuntu VM (using GNU GCC not Mingw) everything works as intended. It seems to be an issue with Mingw or MSYS2.

Is there anything I missed with my MSYS/Mingw setup or anyting else I could try to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Eclipse Window CDT pkg-config setting
   project->properties->setting->pkg-config tab

[pkg-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQBpi.png)

2. Tool Chain Change MinGW GCC -> Linux GCC
   because-> in Windows msys2 pkg-config linux style path generate

[Tool chain change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnPt0.png)

Comment: Add description how your answer gonna fulfill the op's problem. Straight to the marks answer are more helpful with a detailed explanation of its behavior.